# uitableviewcontroller reload section header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is there a way to reload a particular section header in UITableViewController?

Or alternatively, is there a way to access the current instance of the view in the section header?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created an instance of a `UIView` for the UITableView header, then you can access it as you would any other object. In this example, **`footerView`** is a `UIView`.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if ( footerView == nil ) 
    {
        footerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [footerView addSubview: someSubview];
    }

    //return the view for the footer
    if ( section == 2 )
        return footerView;

    return nil;
}
```